# Find error in Solution for Max Sum Path in Binary Tree

Tags: java, dynamic, binary-tree

**The Question is:**

Given a binary tree, find the *maximum path sum*.

The path can *start* and *end* at any node in the tree.

**Example:**

Given the binary tree:

```
   1
  / \
 2   3
```

Return 6.

My Initial Solution was: Passed 90/92 Test Cases on LeetCode

```
public class Solution {

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//This is to handle the scenario where the value of all nodes is negative

    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode a) {

        if(a == null){
            return 0;
        }

        int sum = maxSum(a);

        return max > sum ? max : sum;
    }

    public int maxSum(TreeNode node){

        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }

        //handling the scenario where sum of any path is not greater than the value of single node
        if(node.val > max){
            max = node.val;
        }

        int leftChildSum = maxSum(node.left);

        //path from current node to left child is maximum
        if(node.val + leftChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + leftChildSum;
        }

        int rightChildSum = maxSum(node.right);

        //path from current node to right child is maximum
        if(node.val + rightChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + rightChildSum;
        }

        ////path from left child to right child via current node is maximum
        if(node.val + leftChildSum + rightChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + leftChildSum + rightChildSum;
        }

        return Math.max(node.val + leftChildSum, node.val + rightChildSum);
    }
}
```

But I believe this Solution should be modified.
Consider a scenario where a node has positive value and its `leftChildSum` and `rightChildSum` both are *negative*. In this case then node's value should be returned.

Modified Solution: Passed 63/92 Test Cases on LeetCode

```
public class Solution {

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;//This is to handle the scenario where the value of all nodes is negative

    public int maxPathSum(TreeNode a) {

        if(a == null){
            return 0;
        }

        int sum = maxSum(a);

        return max > sum ? max : sum;
    }

    public int maxSum(TreeNode node){

        if(node == null){
            return 0;
        }

        //handling the scenario where sum of any path is not greater than the value of single node
        if(node.val > max){
            max = node.val;
        }

        int leftChildSum = maxSum(node.left);

        //path from current node to left child is maximum
        if(node.val + leftChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + leftChildSum;
        }

        int rightChildSum = maxSum(node.right);

        //path from current node to right child is maximum
        if(node.val + rightChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + rightChildSum;
        }

        ////path from left child to right child via current node is maximum
        if(node.val + leftChildSum + rightChildSum > max){
            max = node.val + leftChildSum + rightChildSum;
        }

        //Changes are below
        int temp = node.val;
        int value = Math.max(temp, node.val + leftChildSum);
        value = Math.max(temp, node.val + rightChildSum);
        return value;

    }
}
```

Can someone please help me figure out whats wrong with my modified solution?

Comment: not sure, but should this belong on codereview?

Comment: @1blustone nope. Code does not work as intended, OP is asking for help figuring out where the bug is; that's off-topic on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

There was a minor mistake in 2nd solution:

Instead of writing:

int value = Math.max(temp, node.val + leftChildSum);

```
value = Math.max(temp, node.val + rightChildSum);
```

I should have written:

int value = Math.max(temp, node.val + leftChildSum);

```
value = Math.max(value, node.val + rightChildSum);
```